# text box error in android

Tags: java, android, text, title, titlebar

hi in my app i have 2 Activity named as A and B.

Now i am placing 2 edit boxes for typing the first name and last name, with an OK button in Activity A.

After entering the data and pressing OK button i want to show the first name and last name as the title text of Activity B.

i have tried and succeed in passing those names to be subject of my mail in the same app.

pls help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [getStringExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) with your Intent to pass String parameters to a new Activity.

In Activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("firstName", firstName);
intent.putExtra("lastName", lastName);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity B:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String firstName = getIntent().getStringExtra("firstName");
    String lastName = getIntent().getStringExtra("lastName");
        ....
}
```

There are also `getFooExtra` and `putExtra` methods for all of the other basic datatypes.