# queries on button operations of android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

in the main activity of my app i have placed a button named as setting, if i click the button it moves to a new page where i have placed two buttons.

if i click in any of those buttons i want its corresponding operations to be done in another activity,how to do this...

in the same way if i click a button in Activity A, i need a button to be completely invisible in some other Activity...

how to do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to pass messages through the `Intent` that you use to start an activity. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410551/text-box-error-in-android/5410625#5410625) gives a detailed code sample for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can send some data along with the intent, which you used to start the other activity.
For eg, in Activity A

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class)
b.setBooleanExtra("isButtonVisible", false);
startActivity(i);
```

Now in Activity B, in it's onCreate() method, use

```
boolean isButtonVisible=getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isButtonVisible);
if(!isVisible)
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) //Or do something with that
```

I think you got the idea now?